# Any way to make my Dash app run faster for a huge amount of data?

Tags: python, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

I have created a Dash app to read data from a .csv file and represent it, where the user has the option to choose which variable he wants to represent.
The problem I'm facing is that the Dash app keeps freezing or is very slow, most likely due to the amount of sheer data I'm reading (the .csv files I need to read have above 2 million lines).

Is there any way I can make it faster? Maybe optimizing my code in some way?
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import lines
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, html, dcc,Input, Output
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import webbrowser

print("Checkpoint 1")

def open_file():
    global df, drop_list
    Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
    filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
    print(filename)
    newfilename = filename.replace('/', '\\\\')
    print(newfilename)

    df = pd.read_csv ('' + newfilename, sep=";", skiprows=4, skipfooter=2, engine='python')   # Read csv file using pandas


    # Detect all the different signals in the csv
    signals = df["Prozesstext"].unique()
    signals = pd.DataFrame(signals)                 # dataframe creation

    signals.sort_values(by=0)                       # after the dataframe is created it can be sorted

    drop_list = []                                  # list used for the dropdown menu
    for each in signals[0]:
        drop_list.append(each)


app = Dash(__name__)

fig = px.line([]) #figure starts with an empty chart

open_file()

print("Checkpoint 2")

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1(id = 'H1', children = 'Reading Data from CSV', style = {'textAlign':'center','marginTop':40,'marginBottom':40}),
    dcc.Dropdown(drop_list[:-1],id='selection_box'),
    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
    
    dcc.Graph(
        id='trend1',
        figure=fig
        )

])

webbrowser.open("http://127.0.0.1:8050", new=2, autoraise=True)

# FIRST CALLBACK
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='trend1',component_property='figure'),
    Input('selection_box', 'value'),
    prevent_initial_call = True
)

def update_trend1(value):
    df2 = df[df['Prozesstext'].isin([value])] #without empty spaces it can be just df.column_name 
    return px.line(df2, x="Zeitstempel", y="Daten", title=value, markers = True) # line chart


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
    #app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Did the answer help you to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

- Build a **Multi-value** dropdown menu with the names of all columns in the CSV file. Look at this [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/dropdown).
- Based on the selected columns by a user, the corresponding data will be imported from the CSV file.
- It is not clear in your question how you represented the csv data on Dash. I recommend [dbc.Table](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/table/).

By doing this, you will minimize the cost of reading the entire data from the CSV file.